# How can round a number in c#

Tags: c#, rounding

I have values like

```
1.5
2.6
2.499
10.5
11.4999
```

I want to like this

```
 2
 3
 2
11
11
```

How is it possible
In C#

C# Code

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text= Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text)).ToString();

    }
```

Output is wrong
values

1.5   result 2 Correct

1.4   result 1  correct

10.5  result 10, it is wrong Result should be 11

Comment: You are converting `10.5` to `10` before rounding it with `Convert.ToDecimal()`, use `Convert.ToDouble()` instead

Comment: The same problem I want to like input 10.5 output 11 But it is not working it is returning 10 if I input 10.6 then it is fine and returning 11.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.Round(1.5);` function, it will round the number to the nearest integer.

Comment: Not working for 10.5

Comment: please add your code to the question, it is not possible

Comment: Code Added, please check